Nature of Roots of a Quadratic Equation with a Discriminant that is a Perfect Square
I am reading a high school textbook. Previously, the term perfect square was introduced as a polynomial of the form (x+a)², and by expanding, (x+a)² = x² + 2ax + a², and (x-a)² = x² - 2ax + a².
Later, in the context of discriminants, it mentions that if the discriminant b²-4ac can be written as a perfect square (this time defining a perfect square as a number like 1, 4, 9, 16, 16/9, 25/4 etc i.e. numbers that if you take the square root of them, the answer will be a rational number. The book says that if the discriminant is a perfect square, then the roots of the quadratic equation will also be rational. This makes sense.
It then introduces the following worked example:
Given the equation px² + (p+q)x + q = 0:
(i) Show that the roots are real for all values of p and q ∈ R.
(ii) Show that the roots are rational.
(iii) Hence find (a) the roots, in terms of p and q, and (b) the factors, in terms of p and q.
Parts (i) and (iii) make sense to me. For reference, for part (i), the discriminant can be simplified to p²-2pq+q², which can be rewritten as (p-q)², a relationship which we saw earlier when we were introduced to perfect squares. Since p and q are both real numbers, squaring them will result in 0 (if p = q) or a positive number (if p ≠ q). This means that the discriminant is non-negative and therefore the root or roots are real numbers.
For part (ii), the book says that since b²-4ac = (p-q)², the discriminant is a perfect square. Therefore, the roots must be rational.
For part (iii), you can use the quadratic formula to find that x = -q/p or x = -1. Hence the roots would be (px+q) and (x+1).
I don't understand how part (ii) is correct for all real numbers. If p and q are rational numbers, it makes sense that when applying the quadratic formula, all terms will be rational, and the square root of (p-q)² will be p-q, both rational numbers.
However, what if p and q are irrational numbers e.g. surds? If for example, p = √2 and q = √3, wouldn't the roots be -1 and -√3/√2? The second root is not rational.
Am I missing something, or is the book incorrect for suggesting that p and q ∈ R? This is mentioned in part (i) but would presumably carry forward to part (ii).
Is there some kind of relationship between the perfect squares of polynomials (mentioned first in the textbook and the start of this post) and perfect squares of integers and rational numbers (mentioned in the same section of the textbook as this example and in the second paragraph of this post)? It seems to me that referring to both of these things as perfect squares is problematic, as I simply cannot see how the square root of a perfect square polynomial must in all cases be a rational number.
I have spent a few hours trying to understand this, and I am now convinced that the book must be wrong to assert that p and q could be any real number, and instead p and q should be classified as rational numbers for the reasoning used in part (ii) to make sense.
I would greatly appreciate a second opinion on this. Thank you!

Part 2 is not correct for all real numbers.
The assertion that perfect-square-discriminant implies rational-roots generally requires the assumption that the coefficients of the quadratic equation are rational.
There are two possibilities:

Either you excerpted the book out of context, and the book previously indicated that the coefficients were assumed to be rational (or assumed to be integers).

Or the book made an analytical error.



Thank you so much for your answer. I don't believe the book indicated that the coefficients were assumed to be rational. I believe that the assertion that p and q are real is to exclude complex / imaginary solutions, without regard to the following question.
